# Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined after updating user

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have came across this bug. When I am updating a user I get following error from the interface:

*Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined*

The weird thing is, the user updates even when this error message is displayed. Also, there is no error in developer console.

Here is the part of the code in my *ODataProvider* that should update the user.

```
      case UPDATE:
          url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}(${params.id})`;
          options.method = 'PUT';
          params.data = removeProperties(params.data, ['id', 'odata', 'odata.metadata']);
          options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
          break;
```

removeProperties constant:

```
const removeProperties = (data, props) => {
  for (let prop of props) {
    delete data[prop];
  }

  return data;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i can't understand but you can use state and axios to call api then setstate to change user data !

Comment: Can you provide removeProperties function.

Comment: @Atul edited the question.

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined" error log? in the console? can you attach the stacktrace too?

Comment: @sebbab frontend returns this message, there is no error in console as I said in the question.

Comment: can you try changing your for loop as,
  for (let prop of props) {
   if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop))
     delete data[prop];
  }

Comment: In your dataprovider what does UPDATE return to react-admin?  I don't see that in the code you provided.

Comment: @ShawnK

It returns undefined.